# How to install nano on boot2docker?

Tags: boot2docker, nano

How can i use nano on boot2docker? there is no package manager and when i write this command

`nano testo.txt`

it shows

```
-sh: nano: not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
tce-load -wi nano
```

and if it shows this error:

```
Error opening terminal: cygwin.
```

type this:

```
TERM=xterm-color
```